# Возрват массива из JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

Я пытаюсь сохранить информацию о пикселях в localStorage с помощью getImageData. Сам объект вроде сохраняется, но как считать значения обратно?

```
c1.onmousedown = function(event)
{
    c1.onmousemove = function(event)
    {
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        var colorLine = "#C70039"
        ctx.fillStyle = colorLine;
        ctx.fillRect(x-5,y-5,75,75);
    }
    c1.onmouseup = function(){
        c1.onmousemove = null;
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,c1.height,c1.width);
        console.log(imgData.data);
        localStorage.setItem('A', JSON.stringify(imgData));
        var localStorageGetA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('A'));
        //console.log(localStorageGetA.data[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

var imgData = ctx.getImageData(50, 50, 100, 100);
localStorage.setItem('A', JSON.stringify(imgData));
var localStorageGetA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('A'));
console.log(localStorageGetA.data[3]);
```

https://codepen.io/programmwriter/pen/dgPwvg

Смоделировал, впринципе работает.

Comment: У меня почему-то консоль выдаёт ошибку localStorageGetA.data is undefined